# Push data to different elements, depending on column in google spreadsheet with GAS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in Google Spreadsheet with GAS, and I am trying to push some data from a spreadsheet to an HTML page, and right now that is working. But I am managing to do is grabbing all the values, and each time it hits a new row, it grabs all the values in that row pushes them into a newly created `<div>`. But I would like to do is have some column functionality also so that the different columns gets pushed to a different element like an `<input>` or a `<select>` element.

I tried out some things where I declared some variables for the desired columns, and trying to pushing them to the HTML one by one, but it didn't work out.

Here is my data:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the HTML:

[image]

This is what I am going for:

[image]

Would it be better to publish this into tables? Because I simply thought of creating divs with classes and set their width and line breaks?

Below is the code I described in the beginning:

Code.gs

```
var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1c7IwmyBrbNq5xwzo-7EyFewCx31WpfP4EzLpkHawffI");

function doGet(request) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('stuff')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getStitchOrders(){
var ordersName = [];
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cat1");
var subRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
var orders = subRange.getValues(); 

for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {

ordersName.push( orders[i] )
}
return ordersName;
}
```

stuff.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="orders">
//Data is listed here.
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOrderList).getStitchOrders();
});

function buildOrderList(ordersName) {
var rows = $('#orders');
for (var i = 0; i < ordersName.length; i++) {
rows.append('<div name="' + ordersName[i] + '">' + ordersName[i] + '</div>');
}
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Edit

Code2.gs

```
 var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1c7IwmyBrbNq5xwzo-7EyFewCx31WpfP4EzLpkHawffI");

function doGet(request) {
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('stuff2')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getStitchOrders(){
var ordersName = [];
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
var subRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
var orders = subRange.getValues(); 

for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
ordersName.push( { 
name: orders[i][0], 
status: orders[i][1],
comment: orders[i][2]
} );
}
return JSON.stringify(ordersName);
}
```

stuff2.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="orders">
</div>

<script>

$(function() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOrderList).getStitchOrders();
});

function buildOrderList(ordersName) {
var arr = JSON.Parse(ordersName);
var rows = $('#orders');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
rows.append('<div name="' + arr[i].name + '">' +  arr[i].name  + '</div>');
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider returning the data with this type of pattern:

```
for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
  ordersName.push( { 
    name: orders[i][0], 
    status: orders[i][1],
    comment: orders[i][2]
  } );
}
return JSON.stringify(ordersName);
```

then back in the client-side JS we can turn it back into an Array to loop through:

```
function buildOrderList(ordersName) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(ordersName);
  var rows = $('#orders');
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // values can now be referenced via...
    // arr[i].name
    // arr[i].status;
    // arr[i].comment;
    rows.append(...);
  }
}
```

how to then style the divs and the elements inside them to align up like a table is more a CSS question.

Comment: Hello, I tried it out, it didn't seem to work? I my updated code under Edit, I was inspecting the element in chrome, and it looks like fails on "Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function" Any Idea? But thanks for replying, it was exactly what I was looking for, this way I can specify each column :)

Comment: Hey, after I wrote the comment I searched it, and found example of parse with a small "p", before you made the edit which makes more sense anyways. This really worked for me thanks alot :)